# Modify images urls in products

Tags: magento2.4.3

I need to modify the urls of images in 1737 products. At the begin the "/" is missing.

I export products in csv, i modify the urls and then i try to upload it again. But the issue there is that magento try to find the images in var/import/images/

How can i change this urls without uploading images?

Comment: Hi, why not adding "/" in image's value in CSV ?

Comment: i did this, but when i try to import this csv magento try to find images in var/import/images/ folder
Additional data: <div class="messages"><div class="message message-error error"><div data-ui-id="messages-message-error" >Notice: hash_file(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in /home/stagingd/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php on line 1961</div></div></div>
in this line it is
   private function getFileHash(string $path): string
    {
        return hash_file(self::HASH_ALGORITHM, $path);
    }

Comment: i also try to import in db with
ALTER TABLE 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' MODIFY COLUMN 'value';



REPLACE INTO 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' ('value_id', 'attribute_id', 'value', 'media_type', 'disabled') VALUES
(13584, 88, '/o/m/om-5e_1_2nd.png', 'image', 0),
wrong syntax